# Is there a programmatic method to view bluetooth devices that are blocked?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

A device can be blocked like so:
`bluetoothctl block FC:69:47:7C:9D:A3`

Is there a programmatic method to list devices which have already been blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documented way to interface with the BlueZ Bluetooth stack is with the D-Bus API. The D-Bus API allows most languages to interface with it if the language has D-Bus bindings.

Here is an example using Python and the [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) library:

```py
import pydbus

dev_iface = 'org.bluez.Device1'
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
mngr = bus.get('org.bluez', '/')

mngd_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()

for path, info in mngd_objs.items():
    blocked = info.get(dev_iface, {}).get('Blocked')
    if blocked is not None:
        address = info.get(dev_iface, {}).get('Address')
        print(f'[{address}] is {"Blocked" if blocked else "Not Blocked"}')
```

The BlueZ device API is documented at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check the `info` file:

```
grep Blocked /var/lib/bluetooth/*/FC:69:47:7C:9D:A3/info
```

It will return:

```
Blocked=true
```